# Using thread to open form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms

I am currently studying VB.NET and I got question about using thread to open the form.

For example, when I click open button, then tread will start and open another form to adding or changing data.

Therefore, I tried to implement this part such as

```
Private Sub menu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menu.Click       
    Dim A As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Task_A)
    A.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Task_A()
    frmBuild.Show()
End Sub
```

However, I am getting error to open the `frmBuild` by thread. Do I need to use other method to  open form?

And, How can we kill the thread when fromBuild closes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is almost always a bad idea.  You shouldn't try to use a separate thread to open a `Form`  - instead, open all of your forms on the main UI thread, and move the "work" that would otherwise block onto background threads.  `BackgroundWorker` is a common means of handling the work.

That being said, if you need to do this for some unusual reason, you need to do two other things.

First, you need to set the apartment state of that thread.  You also need to use `Application.Run` to display the form, and that form must be created on the proper thread:

```
Private Sub menu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menu.Click       
    Dim th As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Task_A)
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Task_A()
    frmBuild = New YourForm() ' Must be created on this thread!
    Application.Run(frmBuild)
End Sub
```

In order to close the Form from the other thread, you can use:

```
frmBuild.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() frmBuild.Close()))
```

> And, How can we kill the thread when fromBuild closes ?

The thread will automatically shut down when the form is closed, if it's written as shown above.

Comment: when i run program and open with opening extra form, I can't control another form. I am assuming that two form is running one thread. I want.. for example, I would like to use form "B" , when form "A" running an application. Is there any solution to do this idea without using Thread ?

Comment: @BobMa You can open as many forms as you want in a single application.  You need to move your work into background threads - look at BackgroundWorker, for example...

Comment: I think, i got an idea for what to do. thanks!!!!! I didn't know about BackgroundWorker :)

Comment: This was posted long ago, but it saved my life today. Thank you very much!

Comment: This worked but one thing is noticed while debugging is that,  frmBuild.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() frmBuild.Close())) is not immedately  closing the form. i had an if block under that line, only when its done, the form gets closed. is that normal?

Comment: @anandhu Yes, that's normal. BeginInvoke "schedules" the work to happen on the UI thread, so it happens later.